# Is integrate with google button supported on older versions of IE like IE 7 or older?

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

I am currently using IE 10. In IE 10 "integrate with google button" for apps market place is displayed perfectly.
But when I turn on Compatibility View on IE 10 then that button is not getting displayed.
I just want to know the supported browsers for this button.
Thanks in advance.